# A field or property with the name 'Click on Checkbox' was not found on the selected data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am getting above error when I change DropDownSelected Index.

AutoGeneratedColumn Property is true. When I add column manually it shows this error:

> {A field or property with the name 'Click on Checkbox' was not found on the selected data source.}

When I remove manually created column code runs perfect.

index.aspx.cs Code:

```
protected void DropDownListDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Doctor WHERE Doc_Id=" + DropDownListDoctor.SelectedValue + "";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridViewDoctorDetail.DataSource = dt;
    GridViewDoctorDetail.DataBind();
}
```

index.aspx Code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<label>Select Doctor Name</label>
<br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListDoctor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="Doctor_DataSource" DataTextField="DocName" 
        DataValueField="Doc_Id" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownListDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Doctor_DataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Data Source=IM-82B70624D72D;Initial Catalog=AppointmentScheduler;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=za3452432760za" 
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Doc_Id], [DocName] FROM [Doctor]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <label>Doctor Detail</label>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewDoctorDetail" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="339px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Click on Checkbox" HeaderText="Checkbox" 
                SortExpression="Click on Checkbox" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DoctorDetail_SqlDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Data Source=IM-82B70624D72D;Initial Catalog=AppointmentScheduler;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=za3452432760za" 
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Doctor] WHERE ([Doc_Id] = @Doc_Id)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListDoctor" DefaultValue="1" 
                Name="Doc_Id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your explanation is a bit confusing... If I am understanding though, when you update it manually you get the error, and if you don't add it manually, you do get the error?

Comment: whats your `[Doctor]` table schema?

Comment: Doc_Id,DocName,Timing_Id,Adress,ContactNo,Email,Gender,Age,Qualification. This is my [Doctor] table Schema. Yes you got right, when I add column manually it generate an erro.

Answer (score 0):

It is attempting to bind the checkbox to a property "Click on Checkbox" on your data source. Change DataField to Text in CheckBoxField.

```
<asp:CheckBoxField Text="Click on Checkbox" HeaderText="Checkbox" SortExpression="Click on Checkbox" />
```

Comment: When I do it checkbox has been disappeared.